# Django/Heroku After pushing a new version certain templates do not update

Tags: django, heroku

I have made some changes to a Django template, saved them, committed them to git, pushed to GitHub and then deployed this new version to Heroku.

The build succeeds and I can view the template but the change is not there.

I checked the GitHub repo, the change is there. When I check the activity feed on Heroku I can see the change when I click the `Compare diff` link.
When I make changes to other areas of the project, `views` etc there's no problem, I have updated other templates without issue but can not get the new CSS into the deployed version.
Inspecting the code of the deployed version shows the old CSS not the new so it isn't just an issue with my stylesheet, inheritance or so on.

I've run out of ideas, any suggestions of how I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you do `heroku run bash` then use `ls` command to compare filenames on remote with the ones you have locally? There should all match, sometimes the problem is they get capitalized on remote.

Comment: You need to restart your webserver

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer, it seems a little like using a sledge hammer to crack a nut but ...

Anyway I deleted the templates directory, went through a cycle of commit, push deploy. Reinstated the templates directory redid the commit, push, deploy cycle and for whatever reason the CSS is now being picked up and displayed as expected.

I still have no idea what the original problem was, why it happened or how probable it is I will have the same sort of issues again so any suggestions, explanations and clarifications would still be much appreciated.